# What's the word for an outdoor hallway?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, synonyms

Sometimes at motels or hotels or apartments, the hallway is on the side of the building with railing. I can't think of the word for this.

If I call it a "hallway," I think it might be visualized incorrectly by those reading.

The closest word I could think was a "landing." Is that right?

Comment: *Balcony*, perhaps?

Comment: *breezeway*: https://www.yourdictionary.com/breezeway

Comment: Perhaps *veranda*?

Answer (score 3):

You could try "walkway". https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/walkway and https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/walkway
I'd suggest this as perhaps the best alternative. Speakers of any type of English would surely know what you meant.

Here are suggestions of a few synonyms for walkway: https://www.thesaurus.com/browse/walkway
They include "loggia", "gallery", "passageway", and others.
I would suggest that they sound a bit more elaborate that what you are describing, and that walkway seems best suited to the use you mention. Of these, I'd say "passageway" would be the best fit, although there's a possibility that it would imply walls on both sides of the passage: https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/passageway

Dictionary definitions of "hallway" suggest that it could fit what you're describing, but you'd clearly need to use the word "outdoor" with it (as you did in your question).
https://www.collinsdictionary.com/us/dictionary/english/hallway

Comment: Other not-quite-right alternatives. A [cloister](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cloister) is a covered walkway around a central square/quadrangle providing access to buildings. Another related design is the [balcony access block](https://canmore.org.uk/thesaurus/1/504487/BALCONY%20ACCESS%20BLOCK), apartments/flats accessed from open balconies running along the side of the building - in this case the term is "balcony" but it primarily applies to multi-story buildings, so I don't know if you could use it of a single-story motel.

Comment: A [peristyle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peristyle) is a covered walkway open at the side all round a courtyard; a [colonnade](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colonnade) is a covered walkway with pillars, often open at one or both sides.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is a really old question, but I'm putting this here in case anyone else needs an answer.

Try "external corridor" or "exterior corridor".  A corridor is just a tract or passageway that connects rooms/apartments and when I look up "apartment corridor" on stock photo websites, it usually pulls up the images I'm looking for even without the added "exterior" descriptor.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Unlike the other terms proposed on this page, this one unambiguously denotes what the OP has in mind: it makes it clear that it serves no purpose other than that of connecting different rooms of the same building, just like an (internal) corridor.

Answer (score 0):

Well, "hallway" always refers to the corridors INSIDE buildings and multi room vessels. As for exterior passageways, they're "breezeways" or "dogtrots" if they have units opening on both sides of the passageway, and if the passageway only has units on one side of it, it's a walkway, or if it's located upstairs, a communal balcony.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).